# How do I put an ActionListener on a JButton created with an ArrayList of Jbuttons

Tags: java, arraylist, jbutton, actionlistener, onclicklistener

I am trying to figure out how to have an action listner on a JButton that I created from an arrayList of JButtons.

here is the arraylist of buttons:

```
public static ArrayList<JButton> myTests;
    public static ArrayList<JButton> selectedTests;
```

here is the logic setting them up:

```
public Devices(String[] testList, String title2)
    {
        myTests = createTestList(testList);
        selectedTests = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        checkedSerialNo = new ArrayList();
        int numCols = 2;

        //Create a GridLayout manager with
        //four rows and one column
        setLayout(new GridLayout(((myTests.size() / numCols) + 1), numCols));

        //Add a border around the panel
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title2));
        for(JButton jcb2 : myTests)
        {
            this.add(jcb2);
        }

    }

    private ArrayList<JButton> createTestList(String[] testList)
    {
        String[] tests = testList;
        ArrayList<JButton> myTestList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        for(String t : tests)
        {
            myTestList.add(new JButton(t));
        }
        for(JButton jcb2 : myTestList)
        {
            jcb2.addItemListener(this);
        }
        return myTestList;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) 
    {
        if(((JButton)ie.getSource()).isSelected())
        {
            selectedTests.add((JButton) ie.getSource());
        }

    }



    public ArrayList<JButton> getSelectedTests()
    {
        return selectedTests;
    }
```

what I don't know is how to make the actionListner or onClickListener for the generated buttons in the array list.

Any insight and help is appreciated.

Thanks!

ironmantis7x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the easiest way would be to create an internal private class.

```
private class MyTestListener implements ActionListener {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // stuff that should happen
   }
}


private class SelectedTestListener implements ActionListener {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // stuff that should happen
   }
}
```

The private classes need to be in the same java file (where you work with your ArrayLists).
Once you created the classes you just have to add the action Listener.

```
MyTestListener handler = new MyTestListener();

//Inside the for-each
button.addActionListener(myListener);
```

If you only need 1 Listener (for one button type that is; like the itemStateListener) just define one private class with a fitting name and add it to the button in the foreach with the function mentioned above .addActionListener

Have a nice day